# iOS required device capabilities autofocus camera

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, camera, ipod-touch

I have an iOS app where I set the `Required Device Capabilities` config setting to require both `still-camera` and `auto-focus-camera` because it needs to run on newer generation devices that have the better auto-focus camera sensor.

I'm now getting users reporting that they are unable to use the app on new iPod Touches (4th gen) and iPad 2 devices.  Both these have the newer camera so they should work, unfortunately I dont have either of these devices to debug with.

Have the device capability settings changed with newer versions of the SDK? If not, why are these device capability settings not allowing users to run the app on devices that should be supported (iPad 2 & iPod Touch 4th Gen)?

Comment: Which devices show in the **Requirements:** list in the App Store for your App?

Comment: Requirements: Compatible with iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPad 2 Wi-Fi, and iPad 2 Wi-Fi + 3G. Requires iOS 3.1.2 or later

Comment: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/goodreads-scanner/id412488398?mt=8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `iPod Touch 4` and `iPad 2` cameras do not have autofocus. I am unable to find the correct documentation though. But there is another [`app`](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/word-lens/id383463868?mt=8) that directly mentions that the results will not be great for that reason.

Comment: It's interesting to know, what keys did they add to Required Device Capabilities to acheive such Requirements: Compatible with iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4, iPhone 4S, iPod touch (4th generation), iPad 2 Wi-Fi, iPad 2 Wi-Fi + 3G, iPad (3rd generation) and iPad Wi-Fi + 4G.

Answer (score 1):

Neither device you mention has an autofocus camera. Pressing the App Store "Install" button on my iPad 2 pops up a dialog saying it can't be installed due to the lack of autofocus.

Comment: Did you file a bug <http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/>? I filed radar://9642670, if anybody wants to dupe it.