# Configuring an app to run only on specific devices

Tags: ios

How can I set up my iOS project to run only on iPhone 5, iPhone 4S, iPhone 4, and all iPads except the iPad 1? I am committing to iOS 6 only.

Comment: It would help if you explained why you want to restrict your app to just these devices. What about the iPod touch?

Comment: BTW - You should rethink the iOS 6 only choice. iOS 7 is in beta. It would be wise to support that too.

Comment: If you want your apps to run on iOS 6 only then Apple will only make the app available to the device thats supports iOS 6.

Comment: What is your reason to not support the others? What about iPod touch? There must be reason: performance, camera capabilities, OpenGL version, anything.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to answer this in a comment but I cannot still comment everwhere. :D

Take a loook at this : [How to configure iOS app to work on specific devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616746/how-to-configure-ios-app-to-work-on-specific-devices)

Answer (score 0):

By setting *Deployment Target* to *iOS 6*, you exclude **iPad 1** and **any iPhone older than 3GS**. Not sure about iPods, but you didn't mention them.

Since iOS 6 runs on **iPhone 3GS** and you don't want to support it, you need to have reason. Tell us and there may be solution.

---

**Edit:** So if the main reason is non-retina display, you can't do much. You are not alone, who would prefer all devices to be retina-capable, but unfortunately… But hey, all retina graphics just works on these devices without a problem, so just leave it like that. Users of those devices know they have poor display.

Comment: hey, thanks, well not supporting 3gs is mainly because its non retina.

Comment: Aha, but then I see another problem: **iPad mini**. It is new device, so it deserves apps, but it has poor display, so with no extra detailed graphics.